# Visualization of immersed submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, intuition, projective-space, visualization

I am trying to visualize the difference between immersed submanifold and embedded submanifold. At first, I thought that, for example, if I can embed manifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and if my friend can find an immersion $f:M\to \mathbb{R}^3$ then immersed $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a shadow of embedded $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. For checking my thought, I consider the Möbius strip. One can embed Möbius strip in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and immersed Möbius strip in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just the limbered Möbius strip. It seems that what 2-dimensional creature sees about Möbius strip is shadow of Möbius strip on $xy$-plane ($\mathbb{R}^2$).(left figure)
[image]

So, if my thought is to be right and immersed $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a shadow of embedded $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$, then I consider the real projective plane and say: the immersed real projective plane has different figures in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (Boy's figure, cross-cap figure and ...) because it has different shadows in different directions. Is that right? If no, why does real projective plane have different figures in $\mathbb{R}^3$? And which part of my idea is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the Moebius strip can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in several ways. If you have a real one, each way you twist it defines a separate embedding. So shadows of the strip aren't limited to different directions of projection, but also different directions of projection of each different embedding (homotopic or not).

Comment: It's not clear what you really want: to visualize the difference, or to prove a theorem about relation between embeddings and immersions? For visualization, the following may be enough (it was enough for me): $\Huge \infty$ is an immersed circle, while $\Huge 0$ is an embedded circle.